# How to use Big Decimal in Jav ATW

Tags: java

```
package SI;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import static oracle.jrockit.jfr.events.Bits.doubleValue;
import static oracle.jrockit.jfr.events.Bits.floatValue;
import static oracle.jrockit.jfr.events.Bits.intValue;

public class SI extends Frame implements ActionListener{
    TextField ptf,rtf,ttf,sitf,atf,citf,atf1;
    Button ab,sib,cib,ab1;
    Label pl,rl,tl,sil,al,cil,al1;
    SI(){
        pl=new Label("Principal:");
        pl.setBounds(15,50,50,20);
        ptf=new TextField();
        ptf.setBounds(150, 50, 150, 20);

        rl=new Label("Rate:");
        rl.setBounds(15,100,50,20);
        rtf=new TextField();
        rtf.setBounds(150, 100, 150, 20);

        tl=new Label("Time:");
        tl.setBounds(15,150,50,20);
        ttf=new TextField();
        ttf.setBounds(150, 150, 150, 20);

        sil=new Label("Simple Interest:");
        sil.setBounds(15,200,150,20);
        sitf=new TextField();
        sitf.setBounds(150, 200, 150, 20);
        sitf.setEditable(false);

        sib=new Button("Simple Interest");
        sib.setBounds(120,400,100,50);
        sib.addActionListener(this);

        cil=new Label("Compound Interest:");
        cil.setBounds(15,250,200,20);
        citf=new TextField();
        citf.setBounds(150, 250, 150, 20);
        citf.setEditable(false);

        cib=new Button("Compound Interest");
        cib.setBounds(240,400,130,50);
        cib.addActionListener(this);

        al=new Label("Amount of SI:");
        al.setBounds(15,300,200,20);
        atf=new TextField();
        atf.setBounds(150,300,150,20);
        atf.setEditable(false);

        ab=new Button("Amount of SI");
        ab.setBounds(20,400,80,50);
        ab.addActionListener(this);

        al1=new Label("Amount of CI:");
        al1.setBounds(300,300,200,20);
        atf1=new TextField();
        atf1.setBounds(390, 300, 150, 20);
        atf1.setEditable(false);

        ab1=new Button("Amount of CI");
        ab1.setBounds(390,400,80,50);
        ab1.addActionListener(this);


        add(pl);
        add(ptf);

        add(rtf);
        add(rl);

        add(ttf);
        add(tl);

        add(sitf);
        add(sil);
        add(sib);

        add(ab);
        add(atf);
        add(al);

        add(ab1);
        add(atf1);
        add(al1);

        add(cib);
        add(citf);
        add(cil);
        setSize(600,600);
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String s1=ptf.getText();
        String s2=rtf.getText();
        String s3=ttf.getText();
        BigDecimal p=new BigDecimal("s1");
        BigDecimal r=new BigDecimal("s2");
        BigDecimal t=new BigDecimal("s3");
        BigDecimal si=new BigDecimal("0");
        BigDecimal a1=new BigDecimal("0");
        BigDecimal a11=new BigDecimal("0");
        BigDecimal b=new BigDecimal("");
        BigDecimal h=new BigDecimal("100");
        BigDecimal c=new BigDecimal("");
        BigDecimal i=new BigDecimal("1");
        BigDecimal d=new BigDecimal("0");
        BigDecimal j=new BigDecimal("0");
        BigDecimal g=d.subtract(p);
        if(e.getSource()==sib){
            b=p.multiply(r).multiply(t).divide(h);
        }else if(e.getSource()==cib){
            c=i.add(r).divide(h);
            j=c.pow(intValue(t));
            d=p.multiply(j);
            si=p.multiply(t).multiply(r).divide(h);
            a1=p.add(d);
        }else if(e.getSource()==ab){
            si=p.multiply(t).multiply(r).divide(h);
            a1=p.add(d);
        }else if(e.getSource()==ab1){
            c=i.add(r).divide(h);
            j=c.pow(intValue(t));
            d=p.multiply(j);
            si=p.multiply(t).multiply(r).divide(h);
            a1=p.add(d);
            a11=d.subtract(p);
        }
        String sit=String.valueOf(si);
        sitf.setText(String.valueOf(si));
        String at=String.valueOf(a1);
        atf.setText(at);
        String at1=String.valueOf(a11);
        atf1.setText(String.valueOf(a11));
        String cit=String.valueOf(d);
        citf.setText(String.valueOf(d));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        new SI();
    }
}
```

This Applet is not working. When I click the button, it throws an error. this error started after I changed all double to BigDecimal. Please help me out. I am stuck here from many days. What is the mistake here. I do not have much idea about BigDecimal. I am new to it. please help me out. Why does it throw an error?

Comment: Please add the error and its stack trace.

Comment: Side note: don't use `setLayout(null);`.

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think this is valid: `new BigDecimal("s1")`.

Comment: `new BigDecimal("s3")` <- What number is s3 supposed to be?

Comment: Maybe you meant `new BigDecimal(s1)` instead of `new BigDecimal("s1")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the variables rather than mentioning it as a `String`,

Your code,

```
BigDecimal p=new BigDecimal("s1");
BigDecimal r=new BigDecimal("s2");
BigDecimal t=new BigDecimal("s3");
```

Should be,

```
 BigDecimal p=new BigDecimal(s1);
 BigDecimal r=new BigDecimal(s2);
 BigDecimal t=new BigDecimal(s3);
```

Also as suggested earlier by our friends, Do not pass empty values *("")* for `BigDecimal` and use `BigDecimal` constants for zero and one,

```
BigDecimal d=BigDecimal.ZERO;
BigDecimal j=BigDecimal.ZERO;
BigDecimal i=BigDecimal.ONE;
```

Answer (score 1):

The constructors for BigDecimal don't accept empty strings.

```
    BigDecimal b=new BigDecimal(""); //error
    BigDecimal c=new BigDecimal(""); //error
```

The format for these requires at least an integer part - see source, it's not marked optional.

Source:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(java.lang.String)

Comment: Also the BigDecimals with `s`'s are probably an invalid format.